# Can you edit webform submission values without invoking payment?

Tags: webform-civicrm

We have a webform that is used for a complex event registration, with all of the registration details stored in the webform and nothing in CiviCRM except the contribution record.

We'd like to be able to edit some of the registration details that users have submitted to the webform, but using the edit submission link leads to the payment part of the submission - requiring that payment details be entered again.

Is there any way to simply edit some of the webform submission values, which aren't connected to the payment, without resubmitting the payment?

Comment: I'd love to see your webform! You might check out an approach of viewing the submission results in a view and then using something like this (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189636/editable-webform-fields-in-views) or editable views module to edit without re-submitting

Comment: Here's the public side of the webform:https://secure.wildsight.ca/get-wild-summer-day-camp-2019-registration

Comment: Another weird approach might be to create a role that did not have permission to the payment component and try editing/saving that way: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_component_roles
note - this is untested wild hypothesis :)

Comment: @LarsSG which payment processor are you using?

Comment: @LarsSG also could you please tell me how did you add T&C page to weborm? thanks

Comment: @Tapash We're using IATS
The waiver is just a page break, a markup field for all the wording, a text field for the initials and a radio select that you accept the waiver terms (there is only one option, "Yes", and the field is required, so you can't submit the form without agreeing to the waiver terms).

Comment: @LarsSG Thanks so much for your reply

Comment: surprised to hear that using 'edit submission' takes you back to the payment form. will have to go look

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution 
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_import

Answer (score 0):

https://www.webwash.net/integrate-webform-and-google-sheets-using-zapier-in-drupal-8/

1. Drupal 8 you can install Webform Remote Handlers module https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_remote_handlers
   Drupal 7 has a similar module (Webform Remote Post) that also works but it is no longer maintained. .
2. Create a Zap in Zapier to connect the results to a Google Sheet.

Now when someone submits a webform, the results are added as a line on the Google Sheet. This allows your non-techy staff to view, edit, sort in a format they are very comfortable with.